# Unable to pie-plot my data in pandas python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I want to create a pie-plot that will show country values. I have a single column csv file that has list of countries where the users are from that I read into a pandas dataframe.
I've tried all sorts of pie-plot tutorials on web but was unable to plot this single column data.

```
fig = plt.pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist(country)
```

Data example:

```
  country
0 BRAZIL
1 INDIA
2 INDIA
3 CHINA
4 RUSSIA
5 BRAZIL
```

Comment: Could you post the errors and show us what your data looks like, please? Also, are you trying to plot a histogram or a pie chart? You say pie but your code says histogram

Comment: Hi raupraha, Im was just trying my hands at anything to get this data plotted. Basically I want country-wise plots which I guess can be achieved by pie as well as histogram.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need to do is count the number of times each country appears before you plot it. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import your data here

#Plot a histogram of frequencies
df.country.value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
plt.title('Number of appearances in dataset')
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
```

[image]

```
#Now make a pie chart
df.country.value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Number of appearances in dataset')
```

[image]